# Get absolute coordinates rectangle of svg element

Tags: svg

How to get absolute coordinates rectangle of svg element?

`svgElem.getBBBox()` is not giving abs coordinates.

Comment: getBoundingClientRect is probably what you want.

Answer (score 1):

`svgElem.getCTM()` will return the transformation matrix of the element.

Then you can use

```
function getTransformedCoords(x, y, ctm) {
    var xn = x * ctm.a + y * ctm.c + ctm.e;
    var yn = x * ctm.b + y * ctm.d + ctm.f;
    return {
       x: xn,
       y: yn
    };
}
```

to convert (x,y) (attributes of your svgElem) into the coordinates system of the nearest viewport element, basically the nearest `<svg>` parent.

Doc
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff972176(v=vs.85).aspx